# Donut Chart with Rounded Corners in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, graph, charts, swiftui

I'm trying to draw a pie/donut chart in SwiftUI. The curveball is that it needs to have rounded corners.

[image]

I managed to get it done with an arc and sharp corners like so:

```swift
struct PieSliceData {
    var startAngle: Angle
    var endAngle: Angle
    var color: Color
}

struct PieSliceView: View {
    var pieSliceData: PieSliceData
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                Path { path in
                    let width: CGFloat = min(geometry.size.width, geometry.size.height)
                    let height = width
                    
                    let center = CGPoint(x: width * 0.5, y: height * 0.5)
                    
                    path.move(to: center)
                    
                    path.addArc(
                        center: center,
                        radius: width * 0.5,
                        startAngle: Angle(degrees: -90.0) + pieSliceData.startAngle,
                        endAngle: Angle(degrees: -90.0) + pieSliceData.endAngle,
                        clockwise: false)
                }
                .fill(pieSliceData.color)
                
            }
        }
        .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
    }
    
}
```

But it seems I need to draw the path with the arc method to get the corners to round?

I'm not sure what would be the best way to approach it...

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `addCurve(to:controlPoint1:controlPoint2:)` Which adds a Bezier curve that you can control?

Comment: I am still trying it. That's kinda where I get stuck. I'm not sure how to calculate the control points.

Comment: This could be a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67342099/uibezierpath-arc-to-create-pie-charts-with-rounded-corners-and-spacing

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

iOS 17 and later

For anyone needing this functionality, Apple has added pie and donut charts to the Charts framework which includes rounded corners.

[image]

Use SectorMark to create a pie or doughnut chart. Using an innerRadius will  create a doughnut chart. Adding a cornerRadius will add rounded corners. An angularInset will provide space between sectors.

```
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Chart(data, id: \.id) { element in
            SectorMark(
                angle: .value("Count", element.count),
                innerRadius: .ratio(0.5),
                angularInset: 1.5
            )
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .foregroundStyle(by: .value("Type", element.type))
        }
        .frame(width: 350, height: 350)
    }
}
```

For a pie chart, remove the innerRadius:

[image]